# XML Parsing and then deserialization error

Tags: java, xml, parsing, deserialization

This is one of production issue, We are using SAXParser to parse a xml file. But this xml has some unknown character which can be parsed by the parser and then we store that xml file in DB as blob. Later when it is try to retrieve the blob from DB it deserialize it resulted with this exception

```
DataContainer Exception: Deserialization Error:
 SAXException
 Character reference "&#56256" is an invalid XML character.
        at com.inventigo.utils.xmlframework.datacontainer.XMLDataContainer.deserialize(Unknown Source) [xmlframework.jar:]
```

We do not know what special about that character. Assumed it is some kind of this ���������. But not sure why it able to parse this and later failed to deserialize.

I can provide more info if someone need.

Here is code snippet:

```
    DataContainer doc = DataContainerFactory.instance().newContainer();
    MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    DigestInputStream digestInputStream = new java.security.DigestInputStream(new DecodingInputStream(in), md);

    doc.deserialize(digestInputStream);
    info.setDocumentHash(md.digest());
```

Comment: It looks like the XML is not parsed while stored in the database, as it is stored as a BLOB object. Is the XML file stored as encrypted in database?

Comment: Are you sure this xml is not being altered during all the backend processes?